# Ideas for mathematics club

Tags: education, advice

I am planing to suggest founding Mathematics Club in next fall.

Here is my attempt for first prototype:

-Sources: films(such as [Dimensions](http://www.dimensions-math.org/Dim_E.htm)), interactive stimulation for  some mathematical ideas(like game of life), dynamical bibliography[Suggested reading](an expandable bibliography,Anyone can add to it), tricks guide(an expandable guide, anyone can add nice trick that helped him).

-Activities: meeting Theorem of the week(weekly), translate an expository article and publish it in University newspaper(monthly), Launch party.

- Any other ideas, or improvements?
- Creating a club does worth the effort ? , or Should I drop the whole
  idea ?

Notes:

1. **-There is no clubs in mathematics department.**
2. -There are few students specialised in mathematics comparing to other departments, such as electrical engineering(So, most of the
   burden on me).
3. -I apologize for my bad english(I'd appreciate any editing)

==================================================================================
Update:
I found this [page](https://maamathclub.pbworks.com/w/page/12474458/FrontPage) from MAA,

> Ever wonder what math clubs at other institutions are doing? This site will help you find out, as well as let you share your best ideas for keeping math club meetings fresh and fun.

Comment: One thing to remember is that activities do not have to be mathematically oriented! Our math club would go out on hikes, a picnic in the park, or gather together for dinner. Of course having mathematical events is great too, but don't get tunnel vision here. And it is definitely worth the effort.

Comment: Most of math club I found on the internet, There main activities are social. However I hope it will attract more students to math major.

Comment: http://mathcircle.berkeley.edu/

Answer (score 2):

There are several mathematics clubs in former Soviet Union, e.g.:

'Omega' (http://mathclub.bspu.unibel.by/?page_id=29) in Minsk, Belarus,

'da Vinci' 
(http://mmf.enu.kz/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=137&Itemid=143&lang=ru) 
in  Kazakhstan.

Maybe it would be useful to contact with them and to change by ideas.

Unfortunately, their sites as a rule are in Russian. But I think you can find in your country Russian mathematicians which help in translation.